# Printing to a plot device created by a function

Tags: r, pdf, plot

I would like to open and name a `pdf` plot device using a function; plot to it at the level that called the device opening function; and then close it using a `dev.off()` command given at that level -- is this possible in `R`?

**Background**

I print a to `pdf` from R reqularly, and as such do a lot of:

```
pdf(file.path(plotPATH, pdfName), width = Wwidth, height = Hheight)
plot( ...)
dev.off()
```

To promote lazyness, I made a function to open the plot device and save me the `pdf(file.path(plotPATH ...))` boilerplate.

The function i created is:

```
pdfMk <- function(pdfName, Wwidth = 480, Hheight = 480) 
{ 
    pdf(file.path(plotPATH, pdfName), width = Wwidth, height = Hheight)
}
```

Which I would like to call as follows:

```
pdfMk("foo.pdf")
plot(...)
dev.off()
```

The problem is that this does not work ... the output is a `pdf` with the appropriate name and in the appropriate place, but it's always blank.

I thought I may have a problem with closures (or something) so I tried stepping through the `pdfMk` function with `debug` and creating the plot before the function call ends, but the output remains a blank pdf (there are no error messages in either case).

Is this possible? If so, how might i achieve my aim?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code works as it's supposed to, except for the default values.

From `?pdf`:

> width, height: the width and height of the graphics region in inches. The default values are 7.

You're creating a document of size 40 by 40 feet.

Comment: thanks v much -- a bit embarrasing that i missed that detail.

Answer (score 1):

Just out of curiosity: why don't you also include plotting and `dev.off()` in your function?
Something like

```
plotpath=file.path("C:","temp")

pdf_wrapper=function(plot_expression,pdfName,plotpath,Wwidth=7,Hheight=7) {
    pdf(file.path(plotpath,pdfName),width=Wwidth,height=Hheight)
    plot_expression
    dev.off()
    Sys.sleep(0.5)
}

pdf_wrapper(plot(c(1,2),c(1,2),type='l',col='blue',lty=2),"test.pdf",plotpath)
```

BTW: In such cases I always include `Sys.sleep(...)` at the end. This is useful if there is a subsequent call of `pdf_wrapper`. I do not know whether this is due to R or RStudio, but sometimes I get corrupted pdf files when I don't include the waiting time. It seems to ensure that there is enough time to turn of the device properly. However, I am using `ggplot2` and for `graphics::plot` this may not be an issue.

Comment: +1, thanks. good tip. the `plot_expression` is sometimes messy, but that's a problem with my code, and your suggestion is a good reason to improve that situation.